# Python Usage of Crypt Function

Tags: python, function, hash, crypt

How to implement the crypt option in Python 3?

I understand that the use is:

```
Hash = crypt.crypt(password, salt)
```

However, the function has a set of different hashing functions. From the documentation:

> crypt.METHOD_SHA512
>   A Modular Crypt Format method with 16 character salt and 86 character hash. This is the strongest method.
>
> crypt.METHOD_SHA256 Another Modular Crypt Format method with 16
>   character salt and 43 character hash.
>
> crypt.METHOD_MD5 Another Modular Crypt Format method with 8 character
>   salt and 22 character hash.
>
> crypt.METHOD_CRYPT The traditional method with a 2 character salt and
>   13 characters of hash. This is the weakest method.

Again my question is how do I chose which algorithm the function uses?

This is a very basic question I can't believe that I failed to find the answer on my own - I apologise if I'm wasting your time.

Answer (score 3):

You pass the method as the salt argument. From the [crypt function docstring](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/crypt.py):

> If `salt` is not specified or is `None`, the strongest
>   available method will be selected and a salt generated.  Otherwise,
>   `salt` may be one of the `crypt.METHOD_*` values, or a string as
>   returned by `crypt.mksalt()`.

For example:

```
crypt.crypt("password", crypt.METHOD_SHA512)
```

Which under the hood becomes:

```
crypt.crypt("password", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512))
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I specify the process? That is could I use SHA512 but provide my own salt?

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from a [Red Hat solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/221403) and @Leonard_Saracini answer (remove the backslash to make it a oneliner):

```
python3 -c 'import crypt,getpass,sys; \
print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

This is should be secure as of August 2018.

Answer (score 0):

using bash:$ `python3 -c "import crypt; print(crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$saltstring'))"`

$6$ is for SHA512 and $ must be escaped by \ if you use a bash terminal like me